# Dollars to Cents in AngularJS for Stripe Checkout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-templates

So I have a value that is returned from Firebase that looks like this:

```
143.418
```

When I run it through angulars currency filter it returns:

```
{{invoice.pricing.graTotal | currency}}

//Returns : $143.42
```

I have integrated Stripe Checkout into my application and it needs values to look like so:

```
14342
```

So Without the decimal points or dollar signs. Not formatted at all. So how would I get the original value rounded and then remove the decimal point to be sent to stripe?

I tried adding variables to the formatter:

```
{{invoice.pricing.graTotal | currency:undefined:0}}
```

But that added the dollar sign and removed the cents all together.

```
$143
```

Comment: `{{invoice.pricing.graTotal * 100}}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply define a filter that uses

```
Math.round(amount * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things, but this worked for me:

```
Math.round(parseFloat(invoice.pricing.graTotal * 100));
```

I assigned that to a variable and injected that into the view:

```
//in controller    
vm.grandtotal = Math.round(parseFloat(invoice.pricing.graTotal * 100));
//in view
{{ vm.grandtotal }}
```

Answer (score -1):

From angularJs:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

So, it must be something like:

```
{{ invoice.pricing.graTotal | currency : "$": 2}}
```

Comment: The OP wants a value in cents, as an integer, without any currency symbol or formatting. That returns a value in dollars, with a currency symbol, and formatted according to the current locale.